# Which data do I have to use for forecasting? The transformed one or the real one?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, data-transformation, dataset

I have a data about museum visitor in 2011-2019. I divide this data into training set (2011-2018) and testing set (2019). The training set is nonstationary so I used Box-Cox transformation and differencing to make it stationary, and then I able to find the best model. If I want to forecast museum visitor in 2020, do I need to estimate the parameter of the best model again by using all of the data? and which data should I use to estimate? the transformed one or the real one? thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome to CV! You should use the transformed data to forecast. After obtaining your forecasts, you should convert it back to the original form. Otherwise of what worth is it to you?

Comment: Whether to re-estimate the model or not is a separate question than which data to be used. For the latter [this](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html) should be extremely helpful in understanding how to retransform forecasted values from transformed data.

Comment: I agree with the previous two commentators if you are using something like ARIMA. For Exponential Smoothing on the other hand (esm) you don't worry about non-stationarity the way you suggested. You instead chose one of the esm models that assumes non-stationarity. In general forecasts use all the data you have. Training data sets are used only to chose a model.